# Is Intel Vt-d actually supported on the ASUS P8P67 Deluxe?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, virtualization, vt-x, vt-d

The title is my question but for context, I have enabled Intel Virtualization Tech in the UEFI BIOS on this motherboard and can confirm in my Proxmox hypervisor that IOMMU is enabled (PCI-E pass-through is my goal here) but that no iommu_groups are established.  [Edit: I can verify that the GPU in question is in fact detected by my hypervisor.  I simply can't seem to pass it through to a VM]

I have seen other users note that vt-d enabling options may be nested elsewhere in the BIOS for ASUS motherboards--such as "System Agent Configuration"--however these menus do not provide any options that seem relevant (memory remap feature = on; initiate graphic adapter [PCI/PEG]).

My CPU on this older repurposed computer is an Intel i7-2600 base model which I have also verified in fact does support both vt-x and vt-d using intel's [virtualization search.](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/52213/intel-core-i72600-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-80-ghz.html)

I can only assume there is an issue with my motherboard model however the user manual does not provide enough granularity to confirm if vt-x is supported and vt-d is not.  Has anyone had any experience with this or any advice how to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: It should support it, but if there isn’t an option to enable VT-d then it is NOT enabled, and from the sound of it cannot be enabled. Finding the one guy with a 10 year old motherboard, the same motherboard, is a tall order. Screenshots of the screen where Intel Virtualization was enabled would be helpful.

Comment: have you updated to the most recent BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, rookie mistake here.  Thanks Essjae.

The BIOS version 3602 (2012) on the P8P67 Deluxe *will enable* VT-D using Intel's Virtualization Technology setting in UEFI.  Older revisions will not support VT-D, but will support VT-X.  I cannot attest when VT-D was implemented in case someone needed other BIOS revisions.  Just update your firmware and this will function as intended for this purpose.

Hopefully this helps someone else with this extremely specific question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).